# add background music for last 5 second or fade in last 5 seconds a mp4 video

Tags: ffmpeg, fade

I want to add background music for last 5 second in a mp4 video.how ? or fade in last 5 seconds. first time fade out then fade in for last 5 seconds.Please help.
I tried

```
ffmpeg -y -r 30 -i a.mp4 -i nn.mp3 -filter_complex "[0:a]volume=0,asplit[0a][0acf];
[1:a]adelay=15s|15s[1a]; 
[0a][1a]amix=inputs=2:duration=first:dropout_transition=0,volume=2,afifo[outro];
[0acf]atrim=0:16,afifo[0acf];
[outro][0acf]acrossfade=d=20[outro]; 
[0:a][outro]amix=duration=first:weights=\'2 1\'[a]" -map 0:v -c:v copy -map [a] output.mp4
```

Comment: You need to write more details. it is not clear, what you are trying to do. and it is not clear, what result you are getting with your current `ffmpeg -y -r 30 .....` command.

Comment: my video has a background music. i want to all audio are as usual.  but background music fade out from begin but fade in last 05 second.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for unclear question. But after trying a day i got the solution for the question.

The code is -

```
ffmpeg -y -r 30 -i a.mp4 -i a.mp3 -c:v copy  -filter_complex "[0:a]aformat=fltp:44100:stereo,apad[0a];[1]volume=enable=\'between(t,0,20)\':volume=.01:eval=frame[1a];[0a][1a]amerge[a]" -map 0:v -map "[a]" -ac 2
```